# Stream camera video from raspberry to Ubuntu machine using Gstreamer and easycap

Tags: ubuntu, raspberry-pi, gstreamer

I am trying to stream Camera image from raspberry pi2 to Ubuntu machine using GStreamer.

the camera is connected to the raspberry pi using USB with easycap.

The code using to stream the camera is :

```
  #!/bin/bash
clear 
gst-launch-1.0 -v v4l2src device=/dev/video0 !omxh264enc ! avimux !udpsink host=192.168.0.102 port=6030
```

and for the Ubuntu, I am using the following

```
    #!/bin/bash
clear
gst-launch-1.0 -e -v udpsrc port=6000 ! application/x-rtp, payload=96 ! rtpjitterbuffer ! rtph264depay ! avdec_h264 ! fpsdisplaysink sync=false text-overlay=false
```

when I am running the codes, the raspberry pi stream the data, and the ubuntu receiving it, but there is no streaming window open and I get the following error

```
WARNING: from element /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstRtpJitterBuffer:rtpjitterbuffer0: Could not decode stream.
Additional debug info:
gstrtpjitterbuffer.c(3247): gst_rtp_jitter_buffer_chain (): /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstRtpJitterBuffer:rtpjitterbuffer0:
Received invalid RTP payload, dropping
```

I am open to suggestions, Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Try the following things :

1. Use the same port number at sender and receiver for simplicity.
2. At sender, use the element `rtph264pay`

   `gst-launch-1.0 -v v4l2src device=/dev/video0 ! omxh264enc ! rtph264pay ! udpsink     host=192.168.0.102 port=6030`
3. Use either of the following commands at receiver to monitor your UDP statistics:

   `cat /proc/net/snmp | grep Udp\:`

   `cat /proc/net/udp`

Additionally you could also use the element `h264parse` in your pipelines:

```
#Sender
gst-launch-1.0 -v v4l2src device=/dev/video0 ! omxh264enc ! h264parse ! rtph264pay ! udpsink host=192.168.0.102 port=6030


#Receiver
gst-launch-1.0 -e -v udpsrc port=6030 ! application/x-rtp, payload=96 ! rtpjitterbuffer ! rtph264depay ! h264parse ! avdec_h264 ! fpsdisplaysink sync=false text-overlay=false
```

Comment: hi vk_gst, thank you for your answer, this script worked:),
but I have a tinny bug, and it goes like this if I start the sender before the receiver, the receiver wait and will not show the video, but if it goes the opposite, it works, do you have idea why it happened ?

Comment: I think its expected behaviour. You would always want a receiver to be listening before sending something. But this behaviour could also depend on the `sink` you are using in the pipeline, which in your case is `fpsdisplaysink`.  You may have to look into the implementation to figure out the behavior. I have used element `glimagesink` before, and starting sender/receiver in any order works fine all the time.